# print number of duplicates in javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to print the total number of duplicates in the array. Instead the total number of elements is printing from the array instead of the duplicates that are there

```js
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

function pairs(a) {

  var pairCount = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
      if (ar[i] === ar[j]) {
        pairCount++;
      }

    }
  }
  return pairCount;
}
console.log(pairs(ar));
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: You want to count the pairs or the number of duplicates ? I see 4 x 10, 3 x 20, so 7 duplicates, is that what you want ? or the number of pairs with identical elements ?

Comment: Could you specify what answer and in what form do you expect in your example? What type of solution do you want an optimized vanilla one or lodash will do?

Comment: btw, you never use `a`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a total number of just the duplicates, meaning `[1,1,2,2,3] // 2`, then the solution can be pretty short and sweet with es6

```js
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

const duplicateCount = (a) => a.length - new Set(a).size;

console.log(duplicateCount(ar));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just get the total count of duplicates, you can create another array with them filtered out, then just get the difference:

```
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];
const duplicatesFilteredOut = ar.filter((a, i, self) => i === self.indexOf(a))
const totalDuplicates = ar.length - duplicatesFilteredOut.length
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of values that have duplicated you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) this way:

```js
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

let res = ar.filter((x, i) => ar.some((y, j) => y === x && i !== j));
console.log(res.length);
```

If you need detailed information about duplicated values, then you can do something like this:

```js
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

let res = ar.reduce((data, curr) =>
{
    data[curr] = data[curr] ? ++data[curr] : 1;
    return data;
}, {});

Object.entries(res).forEach(([val, numTimes]) =>
{
    if (numTimes > 1)
        console.log(`Value ${val} appears ${numTimes} times`);
});
```

Comment: The function `filter` is the worst approach because a new array is created only for getting the length.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` with a special accumulator which provides a `dupes` property as the counter and a `dict` as a breadcrumb of previously counted numbers.

```js
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20],
      dupes = ar.reduce((a, c) => 
                  (a.dupes += a.dict[c] || 0, a.dict[c] = 1, a), {dupes: 0, dict: {}}).dupes;
      
console.log(dupes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object to keept track of each kind of element. Like this:

```js
const ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

function pairs(arr) {

  const pairCount = {};
  
  for (let a of ar) {
    if (a in pairCount) {
      pairCount[a]++;
    } else {
      pairCount[a] = 1;
    }
  }
  
  return pairCount;
}
console.log(pairs(ar));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for already counted values.

```js
function pairs(array) {
    var pairCount = 0,
        visited = new Set;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (visited.has(array[i])) pairCount++;
        visited.add(array[i]);
    }
    return pairCount;
}

console.log(pairs([10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function instead to get the total number of duplicates in an array.

```
const getDupCount = array => {
    const uniqueItems = new Set(array)
    const duplicates = array.length - uniqueItems.size

    return duplicates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to return the duplicates by value in an object:

```js
const values = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

function duplicates(arr) {
  return Object.values(arr).reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc.count[val] = (acc.count[val] || 0) + 1;
    if (acc.count[val] > 1) acc.duplicates[val] = acc.count[val];
    return acc;
  }, { count: {}, duplicates: {} }).duplicates;
}

console.log(duplicates(values));

console.log(Object.values(duplicates(values)).reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0));
```